# Tuning the close/reopen queue for golden tag badge owners?

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen, tag-badges

I think such an improvement would be highly useful for the software, where the golden tag badge owners could utilize their special powers more effectively.

Namely: if a golden tag badge owner opens the close/reopen queue, he see the questions ordered differently. Namely:

- first for them which were marked as dupes and he has already a golden badge (and thus, he can decide the vote on the spot)
- and, between these questions, first the ones for which the fewest votes were arrived until now ( -> least possible non-golden vtc/vtr vote would be wasted)

The improvement could be particularly useful on the vtc queue of the SO, but it would focus the review resources everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already possible - just filter the queue by duplicates and tags where you have a badge. You could even create a list of bookmarks for such filters, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=duplicate&filter-tags=javascript

We tried building in quick links for both close-reason filters and common tags, but the latter brought the system to a crawl so only the former remain:

[image: filter by type links as shown under the close queue on /review]

These are only enabled on sites with a large amount of review tasks.